# cookie used before any other output is sent

Tags: php, cookies

I have three pages:

- index.php,
- login.php and
- logout.php.

The index page redirects you to the login page, if you are not logged in. When you are logged in, it redirects you to index page, where you can log out. And everything is working pretty well. But that's the weird thing, seems to me it shouldn't.

As far as I know. Header, setcookie and session statements can only be used before
sending any output to the browser, but if you look at the login.php page, it already sent HTML code. Why is this not working? What am I missing here?

index.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset ($_COOKIE['uid'])) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Index Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Logged in with UID: <?php echo $_COOKIE['uid']; ?>
    <br/>
    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    } else {
        /* If no UID is in the cookie, we redirect to the login page */
        header('Location: http://localhost/cookie/login.php');
    }
?>
```

login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
    function check_auth() { 
        return 4; 
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['login']) &&  ($uid = check_auth($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])))
    {
        /* User succesfully logged in, setting cookie */
        setcookie('uid', $uid, time() + 14400, '/');
        header('Location: http://localhost/cookie/index.php');
    } elseif (isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {
        /* If try to  go to login.php when you already logged in, we redirect to the index page */
        header ('Location: http://localhost/cookie/index.php');
    } else {
?>
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    <form method="post" action="login.php">
        <table>
        <tr><td>E-mail address:</td><td><input type='text' name='email'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='password'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' name='login' value='Log in'/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
<?php
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php
    setcookie('uid', '', time() - 86400, '/');
    header('Location: http://localhost/cookie/login.php');
?>
```

Comment: You probably have output_buffering enabled in your php configuration. Meaning that no output is actually sent until the php script ends.

Comment: maybe it doesn't send HTML and just redirects to the correct page?

Comment: Buggy code, use `$_SESSION` instead of cookies..

Comment: You should have a cookie with extra information to authenticate the user. Otherwise I could create a cookie on my machine and select a random integer and get into someone's account.

Comment: @Supericy that's it, php.ini output_buffering was ON, i thought the default was OFF, isn't it?

Comment: @JacobZelek ohh, yes thanks, but it's just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

the header() functions in your login.php file are indeed strange. The headers should be already sent and it shouldn't be working.
Why don't you try with

```
bool headers_sent ([ string &$file [, int &$line ]] )
```

to see if the headers are already sent?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php